# Invoke JS function rendered from PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I’m unable to invoke the JS function being rendered from my PHP code, which is supposed to redirect the user after a specified duration.

first I'm not a programmer or coder, so I'm searching here for help to correct maybe a corrupted redirecting code, I used along ago but it doesn't work now. Maybe there is something changed in the code without I know.

```html
<?php
if(isset($_GET['url'])){
 if(isset($_GET['d']) && $_GET['d'] == 1){
  $TheFullURL = '<a href="'.base64_decode($_GET['url']).'"><b><span style="font-size:10pt;"><font color="red">Download Here</font></span></b></a>';
 }else{
  $TheFullURL = '<a href="?url='.$_GET['url'].'&d=1"><b><span style="font-size:10pt;"><font color="red">Click Here</font></span></b></a>';
 }
 
 //--------By:hadutta.com --------//
 $wait_time = 15 ;
 $TheFullURL = '<!-- By:hadutta.com -->
  <div id="waiting_FullURL" >Please Wait ...</div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
    function FullURL(secs){
     secs--;
     if(secs>0){
      document.getElementById("waiting_FullURL").innerHTML = \'Please Wait ...\' + secs
      window.setTimeout("FullURL("+secs+");",6000);
     } else {
      document.getElementById("waiting_FullURL").innerHTML = \''.$TheFullURL.'\';          
     }
    }
  FullURL('.$wait_time.'); 
  // -->
  </script>
}
?>
```

please, help I've no idea about coding, I'm just a user.
Thanks

Comment: This line is incorrectly terminated (though is commented out): `document.getElementById("waiting_FullURL").innerHTML = \'Please Wait ...\' + secs`

Comment: please, I've no experience to deal with the code. I've taken it from a friend years ago. I understand there is something wrong, but I cant correct it. Please, put the correct lines of code here that would make it work. THANKS

Answer (score 0):

You forget to close your variable, and display the contents of the `$TheFullURL`

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['url'])){
    if(isset($_GET['d']) && $_GET['d'] == 1){
        $TheFullURL = '<a href="'.$_GET['url'].'"><b><span style="font-size:10pt;"><font color="red">Download Here</font></span></b></a>';
    }else{
        $TheFullURL = '<a href="?url='.$_GET['url'].'&d=1"><b><span style="font-size:10pt;"><font color="red">Click Here</font></span></b></a>';
        //--------By:hadutta.com --------//
        $wait_time = 15 ;
        $TheFullURL = '<!-- By:hadutta.com -->
            <div id="waiting_FullURL" >Please Wait ...</div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            <!--
                    function FullURL(secs){
                        secs--;
                        if(secs>0){
                            document.getElementById("waiting_FullURL").innerHTML = \'Please Wait ...\' + secs
                            window.setTimeout("FullURL("+secs+");",1000);
                        } else {
                            document.getElementById("waiting_FullURL").innerHTML = \''.$TheFullURL.'\';          
                        }
                    }
            FullURL('.$wait_time.');    
            // -->
            </script>';
    }
    echo $TheFullURL;
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Syamsul Anwar , but still it doesn't work. when I embed the code in a php page and try the redirection, part of the code appears in the redirection page and the counter down doesn't appear . The following appears in the redirection page ( Download Here'; }else{ $TheFullURL = 'Click Here'; //--------By:hadutta.com --------// $wait_time = 15 ; $TheFullURL = '
Please Wait ...
'; } echo $TheFullURL; } ?> )

Comment: You cannot enter PHP code directly into an HTML document. You must put it in a PHP format file and place it on a server that has PHP installed

Comment: Thanks again. But you don't catch what I mean. This code is a php code OK. I embed it in a page in my site . My site uses the wordpress script and the script is built based on php. So I but a php code In a php page, But I can't determine the fault!!!